# Error converting GUI to standalone executable using Py2exe

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt4, executable, py2exe

I am using `py2exe` to convert my program with multiple GUIs to a standalone executable. I used PyQt to create the GUIs. The main script I run instantiates the main UI, which contains buttons, tabs, etc. that can open sub-UIs. The main script is `main_ui.py`.

I followed the tutorial on how to use `py2exe`, so I have the following `setup.py`:

```
from distutils.core import setup
import py2exe

setup(windows=['main_ui.py'])
```

Then, in the CMD: `> python setup.py py2exe`.

I tried creating a practice exe with a simple script and everything worked. However, I got an error when I tried creating the exe from `main_ui.py`.

Here is the output:

```
L:\internal\(path)>python setup.py py2exe
running py2exe
creating L:\internal\(path)\build
creating L:\internal\(path)\build\bdist.win32
creating L:\internal\(path)\build\bdist.win32\winexe
creating L:\internal\(path)\build\bdist.win32\winexe\collect-2.7
creating L:\internal\(path)\build\bdist.win32\winexe\bundle-2.7
creating L:\internal\(path)\build\bdist.win32\winexe\temp
creating L:\internal\(path)\dist
*** searching for required modules ***
error: compiling 'C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PyQt4\uic\port_v3\proxy_base.py' failed
SyntaxError: invalid syntax <proxy_base.py, line 26>
```

Here's `proxy_base.py`:

```
from PyQt4.uic.Compiler.proxy_metaclass import ProxyMetaclass


class ProxyBase(metaclass=ProxyMetaclass):
""" A base class for proxies using Python v3 syntax for setting the
meta-class.
"""
```

This came with PyQt4; does anyone know what's going on? Is this the right way to make my program into an executable?

Answer (score 7):

I have encountered the same problem. There is very probably a better way, but  removing the folder "PyQt4\uic\port_v3" solves the issue.

(see http://python.6.x6.nabble.com/PyQt-4-7-and-py2exe-error-td1922933.html)